# How to join two tables by one or another ID column (python pandas)?

Tags: sql, pandas, join, inner-join, self-join

I am using Python pandas, I would appreciate the code in Python. But you can suggest a solution in Excel or SQL. I have two tables A and B. Table A has two ID columns by which I want to join table B. Table B has one ID column that either corresponds with one or the other ID column of Table A. Here is an example:

[image]

[image]

And this is the resulting table AB that I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First **concat** your resulting dataframes by joining **ID column 1 vs ID column**
and **ID column 2 vs ID column**
After that just make a **left join to original Table A on ID column 1 and ID column 2**, and select only required fields.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('TABLE A',\
                names=['ID column 1', 'ID column 2', 'col1', 'col2'])
df2=pd.read_csv('TABLE B',\
                names=['ID column','col3', 'col4'])
df3=pd.concat([pd.merge(df1, df2,\
                        left_on=['ID column 1'],\
                        right_on=['ID column'], how='inner'),\
                pd.merge(df1, df2,\
                         left_on=['ID column 2'],\
                         right_on=['ID column'],  how='inner'),\
                  ])
pd.merge(df1,df3[['ID column 1','ID column 2', 'col3', 'col4']],\
         how='left', on=['ID column 1', 'ID column 2'])
```

Here is the SQL code, it is the same idea.

```
select "ID column 1",
       "ID column 2",
        orignal_A."col1",
        orignal_A."col2",
        Last_r."col3",
        Last_r."col4"  
        from "TABLE A" orignal_A  LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT A.*, 
                b."col3", 
                b."col4" FROM "TABLE A"  A 
                INNER JOIN "TABLE B" B 
                      ON A."ID column 1"=B."ID column" or 
                      A."ID column 2"=B."ID column")  
                      Last_r USING("ID column 1", "ID column 2");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) + [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html?highlight=isna#pandas.Series.isna) + [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat)

```
import pandas as pd

m1 = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, left_on='ID Column 1', right_on='ID Column', how='left')
m1_mismatches = m1[m1['ID Column'].isna()].dropna(axis=1)
m1_matches = m1[~m1['ID Column'].isna()]

m2 = pd.merge(m1_mismatches, df_B, left_on='ID Column 2', right_on='ID Column', how='left')
df_AB = pd.concat([m1_matches, m2]).drop(columns='ID Column').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_AB)
```

The idea here is to do an initial *"left join"* between `df_A` and `df_B`, and then a second *"left join"* between the mismatches found in the first join (`m1_mismatches`) and `df_B`. Finally, we use `pd.concat` to concat the results.

Output:

|  | ID Column 1 | ID Column 2 | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | myemail@email.com | myemail666@email.com | lol | 9479 | pee pee poo poo | 985023.0 |
| 1 | email@email.com | email2@email.com | bla bla bla | 123 | bla bla bla hello | 124323.0 |
| 2 | hello@email.com | bye@gmail.com | harry potter | 2077 | NaN | NaN |